# On the complexification of a holomorphic bundle $E$

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, complex-manifolds

Let $E\to M$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over a complex manifold. Considering it as a real vector bundle one can complexify $E$ to $E^{\mathbb{C}}$. The bundle $E^{\mathbb{C}}$ is again holomorphic and $E$ is a holomorphic subbundle of $E^{\mathbb{C}}$.

I am wondering what can be said about $E^{\mathbb{C}}$. For example when is $E^{\mathbb{C}}$ biholomorphic to $E\oplus E$? A necessary condition is certainly that $c_1\left(E\right)=0$ since $c_1\left(E^{\mathbb{C}}\right)=2c_1\left(E\right)=0$.

An example would be $\mathcal{O}(k)^{\mathbb{C}}\cong \mathcal{O}(k)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-k)$ on $\mathbb{CP}^1$. In general what can be said about the short exact sequence

$0 \to E \to E^{\mathbb{C}} \to Q\to 0$

and the bundle $Q$? At least $-c_1(Q)=c_1(E)$. When is there the chance of $Q\cong E^*$ and the sequence beening split?

Comment: Are you sure? Isn't the complexitication isomorphic (as a complex vector bundle) to $E\oplus\bar E$?

Comment: I think what you say is correct. However, that does not really spell trouble, right? Because suppose $(E,h)$ is a hermitian holomorphic bundle then $E\oplus E^*$ is holomorphic but as a complex bundle isomorphic to $E\oplus \bar{E}$.

Comment: It definitely spells trouble. $E^{\Bbb C}$ is *not* a holomorphic bundle. As I said, it is isomorphic to $E\oplus \bar E$. Your isomorphism $\bar E\cong E^*$ is very much outside the holomorphic category.

Comment: Yes, my isomorphism is not in the holomorphic category, that was my point, i.e. a holomorphic v.b. can be isomorphic as complex v.b. to a non holomorphic bundle. The holomorphic structure on $E^{\mathbb{C}}$ that I am talking about is simply $\bar{\partial}\otimes \text{id} + \text{id} \otimes \bar{\partial}^E$.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. The complex structure on a holomorphic vector bundle must be compatible with the complex structure on the base manifold — e.g., the transition functions must be holomorphic. So, if $E\to M$ is a holomorphic vector bundle, $\bar E\to M$ cannot be.

Comment: I really fail to see your point. I do not claim that the transition functions $\left\{\bar{g}_{ij}\right\}$ are holomorphic. Obtaining a holomorphic structure on a bundle amounts to finding new transition functions that are holomorphic. Take the isomorphism $\phi\colon \bar{E} \to E^*$ then $\phi^{-1}\circ \bar{\partial}^{E^*} \circ \phi$ defines a holomorphic structure on $\bar{E}$, as it is $\mathbb{C}$-linear and squares to $0$.

Comment: Well, it's taken me a few days to come to terms with this (after 40+ years working in complex geometry). It still bothers me to write $\cong$ when you're working *outside* of the holomorphic or algebraic category and yet working with very holomorphic/algebraic objects. And yet you ask about splitting, which is only an issue *in* the holomorphic/algebraic category.

Comment: @t312t Perhaps I didn't get your question but if you just take $E$ to be the holomorphic tangent bundle of $M$ and try to do your argument, then you don't have hope to obtain a holomorphic bundle $E^{\mathbb{C}}$ since it would be $T^{1,0}M\oplus T^{0,1}M$.

Comment: @john117, of course there is hope of obtaining a holomorphic bundle, e.g. $T^{\mathbb{C}}M$ could be trivial. Further, again by choosing a hermitian metric on $\Omega^{(1,0)}M$ one obtains a complex v.b. isomorphism to $T^{(0,1)}M$ and thus a holomorphic structure on $T^{(0,1)}M$, as I discussed before. See for example D. Speyer answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8484/reps-of-un-for-the-bundles-of-holomorphic-and-antiholomorphic-forms-of-proje) where the same thing is argued.

Comment: What is the map $E \to E_{\mathbb{C}}$ in the short exact sequence?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese it is simply $s\mapsto s\otimes 1$ or $s\mapsto s\otimes i$.